# VPS Email Setup - Can send but can't receive

Tags: email, domain, vps, mx-record, cpanel

Set my first VPS up yesterday and brought a domain name from 123-reg and got the domain working properly.

However today I set up an email account via cPanel. The email account can send out emails but can't receive any.

What changes need to be made so that I can receive email? I've uploaded screenshots of DNS settings on 123-reg and MX Records. Do these need to be change or is it something on the VPS side.

An explanation of any changes needed?

123-reg Basic Settings:

[image]

123-reg Advanced Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your email is going to `mx0.123-reg.co.uk` and `mx1.123-reg.co.uk` as indicated by the MX records in your DNS zone. If you want your email to go to the host named `mail.yourdomain.com` (as represented by the A record in your DNS zone) then you need to change the MX record(s) to reflect that.

The MX record is used to designate the host or hosts that email for your domain should be sent to. As of now, those hosts appear to be reg-123 servers.